# WAMP Using PostgreSQL + Drupal 7 + Multisite + CleanURLs - Not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, postgresql, drupal, wamp

As the title suggests I am trying to run multiple local development sites on WAMP using Postgresql...I have tried so many combinations and none work.

I have 3 sites that correspond to live productions sites so clean-urls is key...

1. site1.example.com
2. site2.example.com
3. site3.example.com

I installed Drupal7 in a local folder on my harddrive at c:\CM\Web\fooproject
I created a hard-link in WAMP at c:\wamp\www\fooproject to c:\CM\Web\fooproject
I edited "sites.php" in the drupal fooproject\sites directory to look like below:

```
$sites['localhost.site1.example.com'] = 'site1.example.com';
$sites['localhost.site2.example.com'] = 'site2.example.com';
$sites['localhost.site3.example.com'] = 'site3.example.com';
```

I added the following to my local PCs hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.site1.example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost.site2.example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost.site3.example.com
```

> I connect to the sites in the browser, e.g. - for site1 at:

```
"http://localhost/site1.example.com"
```

I created a database in PostgreSQL called "site1drupal"
I enabled the rewrite module in WAMP

```
Alias /site1.example.com "c:/wamp/www/fooproject/" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/fooproject/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I edited the ".htaccess" file in the drupal directory c:/wamp/www/fooproject/ to rewrite the base directory as follows:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
 RewriteBase /fooproject
```

I edited the httpd.conf file on WAMP Apache --> http.conf to include the Virtual hosts directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin site1@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/fooproject/"
    ServerName site1.example.com
    ServerAlias localhost.site1.example.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/site1-error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/site1-access.log" common


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin site2@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/fooproject/"
    ServerName site2.example.com
    ServerAlias localhost.site2.example.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/site2-error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/site2-access.log" common


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin site1@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/fooproject/"
    ServerName site1.example.com
    ServerAlias localhost.site1.example.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/site1-error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/site1-access.log" common


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin site3@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/fooproject/"
    ServerName site3.example.com
    ServerAlias localhost.site3.example.com
    ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/site3-error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/site3-access.log" common


</VirtualHost>
```

I copied the "default" folder in the sites directory and created 3 new folders called "site1.example.com", "site2.example.com" and "site3.example.com"

I am able to install the site fine and navigate to localhost/site1.example.com/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls and enable clean urls

BUT the result is that it takes me to an "Internal Server error" page if I click link outside of the homepage :(

The error log says the following:

```
[Thu Feb 13 17:56:14.108803 2014] [core:error] [pid 5268:tid 1636] [client 127.0.0.1:57100] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/site1.example.com/
[Thu Feb 13 17:56:14.109805 2014] [core:debug] [pid 5268:tid 1636] core.c(3518): [client 127.0.0.1:57100] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /site1.example.com/admin/config, referer: http://localhost/site1.example.com/
```

I am sure it is a simple fix but I just can't see it ..too many moving parts.  Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured this out ...

1st) I needed to remove the aliases I created using WAMP because they were only good if I had multiple INSTALLS of drupal (like testing different versions) ..have nothing to do with Multiple sites!

2) You set-up Vhosts for each site using the actual site name... e.g.

- ServerName = site1.example.com

3)  You edit the sites.php file to link what you put in your web-browser (localhost.site1.mwdworks.com => site1.mwdworks.com)

4) You add in your computer hosts file the site name you will put in the web-browser (for local development purposes - this can be any name as long as it matches what you put in sites.php ...)
e.g.
127.0.0.1  localhost.site1.example.com

and viola ...this all works well ...just follows these instructions and you are good)

Comment: All was working well as above. I have three sites working fine, but I added a forth site, which tries to install in the default folder only :(.  I added this site in the same way I added the others and  now it won't configure in the new site folder ...any tips?